# Having troubles with hiding / showing div when width is bigger than

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some problems with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/w6f2gz2o/

When the screen is smaller than 768px, it shows navicon and if you click it a overlay is shown over the hole screen, and a leftside appears.

But if you resize the window to bigger than 768px and then back the overlay and leftside is still there, i want the overlay to hide if bigger than 768px and the LeftSide should not have the Toggled class anymore.

So i have tried some now i tested this code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) { 
        if ($(".LeftSide").hasClass("Toggled")) { 
            $(".LeftSide").removeClass("Toggled");
            $(".Overlay").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

It worked until i changed the width to under 768px again, then i saw that the leftside was still there. Anyone knows how i can do this?

UPDATE: 
Here is only the layout right now, and it works like i want it, but now the button doesn't work so i can show/hide sidebar.

```
<!-- NAVBAR -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default no-margin navbar-static-top">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleMenu" aria-expanded="false" id="menu-toggle">
                    <span class="fa fa-navicon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="Logo"></span>
            </div>  
        </nav>

    <!-- CONTAINER -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- COL MIDDLE -->
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">

                <!-- COL LEFT SIDE -->
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 hidden-xs">

                    <!-- PANEL -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        ELO
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- COL MIDDLE -->
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default PanelMenu">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Newest</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Week</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Month</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Most Clicked</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        ELO
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- COL RIGHT SIDE -->
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        ELO
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle that includes the described functionality?

Answer (score 0):

try writing  `$(".Overlay").hide();` after 
`if ($(".LeftSide").hasClass("Toggled"))` statement.

If you post a little more about the code. May be i can help better.

Comment: Tell me what you need and i Will fix :)

Comment: On this code i tried using the hide system bootstrap have: http://paste.ofcode.org/NUQ3tYrc8qvWEeKHDw5ALD - But it didnt work to well, because its hidden all the time, or not hidden at all. :(